# Looking for a Java library for processing image

Tags: java, image-processing, openimaj

I'm working on a project with image recognition and i'm searching a **Java library** to help me.
I would like to find shape in my image like borders or areas and i'm sure there is many librairies that can help me.

I've already try openimaj but i can't find the exact function i need.

Typically i would to receive an array of vectors or points that compose my image.

Maybe i can use pattern for searching a special shape in this image.

Do you have an idea of the librairy i can use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways:

1- The best way is to use [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/) library.

2- you can use [JIU](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jiu/)

3- you can use [processing](http://processing.org/)

4- you can use [im4java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/)

5- you can use [Marvin Framework](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/)

6- the last way is to use a specialized image processing tool and connect it to java like :
[OpenCV](http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/) OR [MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/), and there are a predifined ways to [connect matlab with java](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/ECC/javaMatlab.html) OR [calling matlab from java](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~whitehouse/matlab/JavaMatlab.html)